# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when implement Google-Sign in for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-signin

I have integrated sign in with Google in my iOS app(Xcode6 and Swift1.2) using Cocoapods.I followed the  below link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift. But I am getting the `Apple Mach-O Linker Error`.

> ld: 530 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How it will be solved?Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: You have duplicates on your project, so check your compile sources

Comment: @EridB Thank You.It was because of the duplicate GoogleSignIn.framework which was previously added manually.Removing it solved my problem.

Comment: You are welcome. I posted an answer just in case someone has this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

File duplication which is caused by adding the same file on the project twice.

### Solution

Click on your project -> **Build Phases** -> Expand **Compile Sources** and remove files which are duplicated.

### Tip

> If there are a lot of duplicated files, select all files and remove
> them, and then re-add them by searching ".m", which will give you all
> implementations files

Cheers